# DBCC CHECKDB: Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID

Tags: sql-server

Yes I know the best option is to restore a non-corrupted database.

But...
Does the following message mean that there is data corruption in unused pages?

> Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID -8573858375060684800 (type Unknown), page (0:13887752). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12716041 and -14.

I have about 200 errors like the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your database is corrupted.The error you pasted indicates ,this corruption may be due to I/O sub system..

You will need to understand what is checksum prior to that..

> when you enable checksum,SQLServer calculates checksum of the page before writing to disk and writes to its page  header.
>
> When the page is read again,it calculates checksum ,if this checksum doesn't match the last calculated CheckSum,SQL will throw error

Run   CHKDSK  as well,to see if I/O subsystem is fine along with DBCC activities

The same issue has been reproed [here](http://www.sqlnotes.info/2013/05/02/fix-page-checksum/)

**Update as per comments**:
Objectid Zero is explained by Paul Randal :[Finding a table name from a page ID](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/finding-table-name-page-id/)

If you see the ObjectId is 0, that means there was no metadata found. This could be because:

> The table that the page was part of has been deleted since the page corruption was logged
> The system catalogs are corrupt in some way
> The page is corrupt and so incorrect values were used to look up the metadata

References:
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-using-dbcc-page-and-dbcc-ind-to-find-out-if-page-splits-ever-roll-back/

Comment: But is my data compromized? Or does the Object ID = 0 and Index ID = -1 indicate the corrupted page is unused?

Comment: So how to get rid of it when the ObjectId = 0?

Comment: you will need to run DBBC checkdb to know about extent of damage

Answer (score 0):

This pattern means that DBCC couldn’t work out which object the page is part of.

> Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID
> -8573858375060684800 (type Unknown), page (0:13887752). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12716041 and -14.

SQL Server has a way of allowing data file pages to be what is called protected on disk. It is actually a real misnomer because what it really means is that it allows SQL Server to detect when a page has become corrupted. It is simply a way of SQL Server being able to tell that the I/O subsystem has corrupted a page. You can turn on page protection options or change the one you have by using `ALTER DATABASE SET PAGE_VERIFY<option>`, there are three different options that you can use:

- The first one is NONE, and I really do not recommend that you do
  that.
- TORN_PAGE DETECTION
- CHECKSUM

Reference : https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/detect-page-level-corruption-automatically/